# Error in dataflow plugins.adfprod.AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime.45

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am getting below error while running my dataflow. This dataflow was running fine till yesterday. From today onwards I am getting error like this

Operation on target LoadAccount failed:
[plugins.adfprod.AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime.45 WorkspaceType: CCID:<1a11d7e0-b019-4845-ab29-641100c79f04>] The job has surpassed the max number of seconds it can be in ResourceAcquisition state [1000s], so ending the job.

Answer (score 1):

> Error Message - The job has surpassed the max number of seconds it can
> be in ResourceAcquisition state [1000s], so ending the job.

In a lot of cases of Data Factory the MAX limitations are only soft restrictions that can easily be lifted via a support ticket.

There is no such thing as a limitless cloud platform.

Refer this [article](https://%20https://mrpaulandrew.com/2020/01/29/azure-data-factory-resource-limitations/) by MRPAULANDREW